# How to pass ancher tag when loading a view in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to load a single page index where i have my form. When the form has errors, i need to show the errros in the perticular ancher tag. Currently i am passing in a variable and running a JS. But since the js runs at onload, the there is a error running ajax: Following is my controller code:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('include/header');
        $this->load->view('include/navbar');
        $this->load->model('Product_model');
        $this->load->model('Country_model');
        $data['categories'] = $this->Product_model->get_categories();
        $data['countries'] = $this->Country_model->get_countries();
        //set destination
        //$data['pageSection'] = 'registration';
        //$tag_var="#registration";
        $this->load->view('site/site_home',$data);

    }
```

the ancher tag where i want to get to is in the commented $tag_var, my JS code is shown below:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#<?php echo $pageSection;?>').offset().top }, 1000);
    $('#category').change(function(){
        var category_id = $('#category').val();
        alert(category_id);
        if(category_id != '')
        {
            $.ajax({

                url: "<?php echo site_url('Site/get_sub_cat')?>",
                method:"POST",
                data:{category_id:category_id},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    //alert(data);
                    $('select.get_sub_category').html(data); //Make sure you update the SELECT element. not the DIV (by adding "select.xxx").
                    $('select.get_sub_category').niceSelect('update');
                    $('#sub_category').html(data);
                    //$('#city').html('<option value="">Select City</option>');
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            $('#sub_category').html('<option value="">Select Sub Category</option>');
            //$('#city').html('<option value="">Select City</option>');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please share you full code? Where is your js code? Also, don't forget to update ```csrf``` on every request whether it is success or not.

Comment: Thank you, i edited the question, also what do you mean by csrf? @AbhishekHonrao

Comment: @AbhishekHonrao i hope no one has an answer here. Thanks any way